# Display none in first child

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

JavaScript

```
$('dl #last div #product-tabs-content').not(":first-child").hide();
```

with this testing code it works perfect but

```
 <dl class="last"><div class="product-collateral row-fluid">
   <constructob>
     <ul class="product-tabs">
       <li id="product_tabs_1" class="first active">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
       </li>
       <li id="product_tabs_product_3я" class="">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)">222</a>
       </li>
       <li id="product_tabs_2" class="last">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)">333</a>
       </li>
       <li id="product_tabs_капут" class="last">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-indent: initial;">444</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </constructob>

   <div class="product-tabs-content5" id="product_tabs_маря_contents">555</div>
   <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_маря_contents">1</div>
   <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_product_неля_contents" style="display: none;">2</div>
   <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_ганя_contents" style="display: none;">3</div>
   <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_капут_contents" style="display: none;">4</div>

  </div>
<dl>
```

But on my live web site this script does not work.

Here is my problem page http://mociko.zupermarket.uz.ua/index.php/profitroli/profitrol.html

The first time, I thought that this is nococflict.js problem but when I set `$jq` in functions anythings happened.

Maybe the problem is in the class/ids architecture, but my knowledge of Java is really pure to fix this problem.

Comment: FYI: Your HTML is invalid in a lot of places … http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://mociko.zupermarket.uz.ua/index.php/profitroli/profitrol.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all of you guys. I fixed my problem by this way.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$jq(document).ready(function () {
$jq('.last .product-tabs-content').not("div:eq(0)").hide();
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting IDs but your HTML shows classes with those names, not IDs. Do you mean this?

```
$('dl .last div .product-tabs-content').not(":first-child").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you have this in your site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[м
setTimeout(display,100);
function display() {
    $jq('dl #last div #product-tabs-content').not(":first-child").hide();

    Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
    Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
      initialize: function(selector) {
        var self=this;
        $$(selector+' a').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
      },

      initTab: function(el) {
          el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
          if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
            this.showContent(el);
          }
          el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
      },

      showContent: function(a) {
        var li = $(a.parentNode), ul = $(li.parentNode);
        ul.select('li').each(function(el){
          var contents = $(el.id+'_contents');
          if (el==li) {
            el.addClassName('active');
            contents.show();
          } else {
            el.removeClassName('active');
            contents.hide();
          }
        });
      }
    }
    new Varien.Tabs('.product-tabs');
    //]]>
}
</script>
```

First of all you need to order that a little bit, you are closing "//]]>" just before to close the bracket, try to put it in this way:

```
    ....
    }
    new Varien.Tabs('.product-tabs');
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Then you are using a setTimeout to execute jquery, that does not guarantee you that all the page is loaded, also you are using a 0.1 second to execute that, basically you are not giving to the site time to load, you can change that "100" to "2000" to test if that works.
Everyway I think you need to do that in another way than setTimeout because the load times always are variables and you never knows what time is the exactly that the page will be loaded.
So you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[м
$jq(document).ready(function () {
    $jq('dl #last div #product-tabs-content').not(":first-child").hide();

    Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
    Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
      initialize: function(selector) {
        var self=this;
        $$(selector+' a').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
      },

      initTab: function(el) {
          el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
          if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
            this.showContent(el);
          }
          el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
      },

      showContent: function(a) {
        var li = $(a.parentNode), ul = $(li.parentNode);
        ul.select('li').each(function(el){
          var contents = $(el.id+'_contents');
          if (el==li) {
            el.addClassName('active');
            contents.show();
          } else {
            el.removeClassName('active');
            contents.hide();
          }
        });
      }
    }
    new Varien.Tabs('.product-tabs'); 
});
//]]>
</script>
```